# Bootstrap 5: Run javascript only with validated form

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a form with various input fields that are validated using bootstrap 5 validation.

```
<form class="needs-validation asset-test" action="{{ url_for('asset_test') }}" method="post" novalidate>
[...]
</form>
```

According to the documentation, the following code is responsible for this:

```
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(() => {
    'use strict'
  
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
  
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
  })()
```

Now I want to execute a javascript function on a successful form send:

```
$('.asset-test').on('submit', function () {
    alert('form submitted');
});
```

But this function is now always executed when the submit button is pressed. So even if some input fields do not have valid content yet and the bootstrap validation fails.

I see that 'was-validated' must be added to each field. Presumably all input fields in the forms must be checked for this? Unfortunately I lack the javasctipt knowledge for this. Can someone please guide me on the right path?

Execute my javascript function only if the bootstrap validation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `else` clause after the call of `checkValidity()` :

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(() => {
    'use strict'
  
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
          console.log("invalid form");
        } else {
          console.log("valid form");
          //add some code here
        }
  
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
  })()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine with only one form. However, if a page has multiple forms, it seems that all forms are checked, even if another has been submitted. this causes the code to be run again here as well.
I have added an if and reset of previous forms, but even then when sending other forms the code in the if is executed. Do you have an idea?

`else {
    if (document.getElementById("test123")) {
        alert("right form")
        var element = document.getElementById("test123")
        element.reset()
    }
}`